# Firebase + Typescript, cannot get accessToken off user object?

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In my MobX store, I can't seem to get the accessToken from the Firebase login. The data is clearly there, though. It is for React-Native.

Sample:

```
class GlobalStore {

    @observable loggedIn: boolean;

    @observable user: any;

    @action firebaseStatup = () => {

        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "somestring",
            authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "app",
            storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1234
        });
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            this.loggedIn = !!user;
            if (user) {
                this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                console.log(this.user); // Returns an Object that has property stsTokenManager.accessToken which is the JWT?
                console.log(this.user.stsTokenManager.accessToken)
            }
        })
    };
```

`console.log(this.user);` results in a big object with all the user information. On `stsTokenManager.accessToken`, the token is present.

if I wish to access the property directly, I get this thrown back:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.user.stsTokenManager.accessToken')
```

How do I get the `accessToken` which is clearly there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `user` returns a promise. I wanted to save it to AsyncStorage, so this was the way:

```
// ... Firebase stuff

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        this.loggedIn = !!user;
        if (user) {
            this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            user.getIdToken()
                .then(token => this.saveTokenToStorage(token))

        }
    });

@action async saveTokenToStorage(token: string) {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('authentication', token);
    } catch (error) {
        // Error saving data
    }
};
```